# Google Places API nearby search rankby distance skipping some nearest places

Tags: google-maps, web, google-places-api

I want to search all nearby places form a certain position. I came to know that it can be done by using Google Places API nearby search by passing **rankby=distance** in parameter. As it is necessary to pass one of these three parameter **name**, **keyword**, or **type** when we are using **rankby=distance** parameter in query. So I gave **type=establishment** in the query and its working but not as i wanted. Problem with the query is that it is not returning all the the nearest places. What should I use to get all places.

And of course Google Places API returns 60 places and 20 on the First Page. But something this query skip most closest place.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=41.89264166666667,-87.62443666666667&rankby=distance&type=establishment&key=MY_KEY.
```

how can i resolve this problem.

Comment: possible related issue on the issue tracker [Issue 8567](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8567)

Comment: related question: [Must-Be-A-Bug in Google Places API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230140/must-be-a-bug-in-google-places-api)

Comment: @geocodezip Issue 8567 is exactly same as mine. but i can't find any solution there. except "Pending Further Review."

Comment: Star it to get informed of updates and to let google know you are interested in getting it fixed.  The status I see indicates that for the time being google has accepted this as an issue with their code and might be working on fixing it.