# Google places API nearby search inconsistent results

Tags: google-places-api

I found that nearby search returns inconsistent results.

I ran this query one day (go client lib). It returned me 4 results. Given

> keyword=Resorts+World+Sentosa+Equarius+8+Sentosa+Gateway&location=1.2564%2C103.8189&rankby=distance&type=lodging

https://gist.github.com/haibin/20e01d38c10d4da9275439c549a2db91

I ran this query another day (go client lib). It returned me 5 results. Given

> keyword=Resorts+World+Sentosa+Equarius+8+Sentosa+Gateway&language=en&location=1.2564%2C103.8189&rankby=distance&type=lodging

https://gist.github.com/haibin/b40e4952b7fddace78d6c37a19542a40

I ran this query today (curl). It returned me 1 result. Given

> keyword=Resorts%20World%20Sentosa%20Equarius%208%20Sentosa%20Gateway&language=en&location=1.2564%2C103.8189&rankby=distance&type=lodging

https://gist.github.com/haibin/a65a6d03ace05898913e306840307bdb

Any idea why?

Comment: Now i am searching why go lib returning more results while curl returning only one :p

Answer (score 2):

Possibly there was a bug in google places API when using `rankby=distance` parameter it skips some result or search in "limited radius"

As when I ran curl with these params

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=MY_KEY&keyword=Resorts+World+Sentosa+Equarius+8+Sentosa+Gateway&location=1.2564%2C103.8189&rankby=distance&type=lodging
```

it returned only one result as u said.

But when i ran with radius param it returns more results as accepted

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=1.2564,103.8189&type=lodging&keyword=Resorts+World+Sentosa+Equarius+8+Sentosa+Gateway&key=MY_KEY&radius=300
```

You are getting more results through go lib because probably they fixed it in that or something like that

For more info you can go through these issues:

[Google Places API nearby search rankby distance skipping some nearest places](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33261681/6700273)

http://www.itgo.me/a/3468386017980994007/google-places-api-nearby-search-rankby-distance-skipping-some-nearest-places

Hope this will help you.